# Keybindings not working from VSCode integrated terminal

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code

I'm attempting to map the vscode commands `workbench.action.navigateLeft` and `workbench.action.navigateRight` to `alt+i` and `alt+o`, respectively.  This was pretty straightforward with the following changes to `keybindings.json`:

```json
{
  "key": "alt+o",
  "command": "workbench.action.navigateRight"
},
{
  "key": "alt+i",
  "command": "workbench.action.navigateLeft"
},
```

This works perfectly when I'm in the context of editors, but does not work when my focus is on the integrated terminal.  I've added these two commands to `terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell` in `settings.json` but that seemed to have no effect.  Nothing happens when I press `alt+i` or `alt+o` from within the integrated terminal.

```json
"terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell": [
  "workbench.action.navigateLeft",
  "workbench.action.navigateRight"
]
```

I'm on a linux system using bash as my shell.  It seems like maybe bash is capturing my keystrokes before vscode has the opportunity to interpret them, but I don't know how to verify if that's happening or how to change it if it is.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you open a Github issue for it because setting `commandsToSkipShell` must be worked but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up being with a different setting in my `settings.json` file.  I had `terminal.integrated.sendKeyBindingsToShell` set to `true` which was intercepting some commands before they could be received by vscode.

This makes sense given the description of that setting.  Setting this value to `false` (or removing from my `settings.json` file as the default is `false`) caused my key bindings to work as expected.